# Create a CFG for $L = \{ a^ib^j \mid \lvert i - j \rvert \le 2 \} $

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free

I'm trying to find a CFG for the following language:

$L = \{ a^ib^j \mid \lvert i - j \rvert \le 2 \} $

What I thought about unsuccessfully is the following:

$S \rightarrow SASBS \mid SBSAS \mid \epsilon$

$A \rightarrow a \mid aa \mid aaa $

$B \rightarrow b \mid bb \mid bbb $

Which has the following problems:

***(1) It does not take into account words that do not have a's or b's***

***(2)
It is possible to add a greater number of a's or b's than the allowed distance, for example aaabaaab is a word generated by that CFG***

I've been thinking about it for a long time and it seems like a dead end because it seems that making CFG's is more of an art than anything else, I would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4124760/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139805/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your language as a union of simpler languages:
$$
\{ a^{i+2} b^i : i \geq 0 \} \cup
\{ a^{i+1} b^i : i \geq 0 \} \cup
\{ a^i b^i : i \geq 0 \} \cup
\{ a^i b^{i+1} : i \geq 0 \} \cup
\{ a^i b^{i+2} : i \geq 0 \}
$$